# Не работает часть программы "банкомат"

Tags: c++

**Неправильно работающая часть выглядит так**

```
 if ((p->NumberOfCash - (AmmountToWithdraw / p->value)) >= 0)
            {
                count = count + (AmmountToWithdraw / p->value);
                p->NumberOfCash = p->NumberOfCash - (AmmountToWithdraw / p->value);
                AmmountToWithdraw = AmmountToWithdraw % p->value; 
            }
```

- `p->NumberOfCash` - поле структуры для количества данных купюр.
- `p->value` - поле структуры для стоимости данной купюры.
- `AmountToWithdraw` - нужная для снятия сумма.
- `count` - счетчик общего кол-ва купюр, нужных для снятия (в моем вопросе не имеет значение)

Главный вопрос - почему при попытке снятия 100 рублей (например) при невыполнении условия `((p->NumberOfCash - (AmmountToWithdraw / p->value)) >= 0)`, т.е. при отсутствии в банкомате нужного кол-ва (например , 1) купюр оно все еще переопределяет значение `p->NumberOfCash` и выводит его в отрицательные значения.
***(СМ. дополнение 1)***

- Дополнение 1:

[image: Нужный кусок кода]
Как так выходит, что -2-4 >=0 ? Онлайн компилятор делает то же самое

Comment: Что то из этих элементов `unsigned int`?

Comment: @NewView да, неужели это имеет значение? p->value Это unsigned int

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, уж не знаю в чем смысл, но сменив unsigned int на int все заработало. :)

Comment: `unsigned xxx` это беззнаковое число, то есть оно не может принимать значения `0 <`